# How to force sbt to resolve dependencies with scalaVersion compatible with the dependent project

Tags: scala, sbt, resolver, dependency-resolver, scala-version-cross-build

Consider the following contents of some `build.sbt` and no source code in particular:

```
lazy val y = (project in file("y"))
  .settings(
    scalaVersion := "2.11.8",
  )
  .dependsOn(x)

lazy val x = (project in file("x"))
  .settings(
    crossScalaVersions := Seq("2.11.8", "2.12.6")
  )
```

Here, `sbt y/compile`, fails with

```
sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: x#x_2.11;0.1.0-SNAPSHOT: not found
```

which is explained by `sbt "show y/fullResolvers"` referring to

```
Raw(ProjectResolver(inter-project, mapped: x#x_2.12;0.1.0-SNAPSHOT))
```

Why does it refer to `_2.12`? I suppose that since `sbt "show y/allDependencies"` lists

```
x:x:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT
```

as the dependency, which misses the `scalaVersion` and the `_2.12`, the sbt does not understand (unlike with external library dependencies) what scala version to look for. The `_2.12` seems to be derived from the `ThisBuild` or `Global` value of `scalaVersion` which defaults to some 2.12.x, changing the `scalaVersion` at one of the scopes fixes the problem for the simplified example above, but if we add

```
lazy val z = (project in file("z"))
  .settings(
    scalaVersion := "2.12.6",
  )
  .dependsOn(x)
```

then what ever value we choose for `scalaVersion` in the `Global / ThisBuild` scope, either `y` or `z` will fail to build.

I am aware of `sbt "+ y/compile"` but why doesn't `sbt y/compile` correctly defaults to matching `scalaVersion` between the dependent project and the dependency? Or can it be made to pick the right `scalaVersion` when resolving dependencies?

---

`sbt "show sbtVersion"` gives me `1.2.1` but I have seen the same problem across different versions, no previous explanation online helped me understand / circumvent the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a Scala version for the project. And it should be the most common version. You can see a general example at [Cross building a project statefully](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Cross-Build.html#Cross+building+a+project+statefully). In your example you can do:

```scala
ThisBuild / scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

lazy val y = (project in file("y"))
  .settings(
    scalaVersion := "2.11.8"
  )
  .dependsOn(x)

lazy val x = (project in file("x"))
  .settings(
    crossScalaVersions := Seq("2.11.8", "2.12.6")
  )
```

Or if for example you go with Scala 2.12 as the default, you can do:

```scala
ThisBuild / scalaVersion := "2.12.6"

lazy val y = (project in file("y"))
  .settings(
    scalaVersion := "2.12.6"
  )
  .dependsOn(x)

lazy val x = (project in file("x"))
  .settings(
    crossScalaVersions := Seq("2.11.8", "2.12.6")
  )
```

Regarding the `z` requirement, I don't think it is possible. I think all subprojects should support the Scala version of the project.